# Kohana combine orm factories

Tags: orm, factory, kohana

I have two factories "News" and "Photoset". Can I somehow combine them?

```
$news = ORM::factory('News')
        ->where('title_'.I18n::$lang, '<>', '')
        ->and_where('image', '<>', '')
        ->and_where('published', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('is_slider', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('date', '<', DB::expr('UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'))
        ->order_by('date','desc')
        ->limit(4)
        ->find_all();

$photoset = ORM::factory('Photoset')
        ->where('name_'.I18n::$lang, '<>', '')
        ->and_where('published', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('is_slider', '=', 0)
        ->order_by('date','desc')
        ->limit(4)
        ->find_all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, just converted them to array and merged.

```
$news = ORM::factory('News')
        ->where('title_'.I18n::$lang, '<>', '')
        ->and_where('image', '<>', '')
        ->and_where('published', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('is_slider', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('date', '<', DB::expr('UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'))
        ->order_by('date','desc')
        ->limit(4)
        ->find_all()
        ->as_array();

$photoset = ORM::factory('Photoset')
        ->where('name_'.I18n::$lang, '<>', '')
        ->and_where('published', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('is_slider', '=', 0)
        ->order_by('date','desc')
        ->limit(4)
        ->find_all()
        ->as_array();

$newArray = Arr::merge($news, $photoset);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is the equivalent of `UNION` from SQL. ORMs aren't made for that...

The second thing is that mapping SQL results to objects in Kohana is slow. (But you don't seem to do that.) If you only need to display the results, it's better to use the query builder.

```php
$q2 = DB::SELECT('id', DB::expr('set' AS 't'))->from('photoset')
        ->where('name_'.I18n::$lang, '<>', '')
        ->and_where('published', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('is_slider', '=', 0)
        ->order_by('date','desc')
        ->limit(4);
$q = DB::SELECT('id', DB::expr('news' AS 't'))->from('news')
        ->where('title_'.I18n::$lang, '<>', '')
        ->and_where('image', '<>', '')
        ->and_where('published', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('is_slider', '=', 1)
        ->and_where('date', '<', DB::expr('UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'))
        ->order_by('date','desc')
        ->limit(4)
     ->union($q2, TRUE);
$newArray = $q->execute()->as_array();
```